# How to Bind The Database value in Datagridview textbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms-designer

I am using Windows form and C# and MySQL.

In that i add three unbound columns in Datagridview with the help of control tag witch is in Datagridview right top.

column1 is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.
column 2 and 3 is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.

After that i wrote code to fill the Datagrid view.

```
connection.Open();
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
                 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select admin_no,name from " + FormName + " where class_code='" + class_code + "' and division_code='" + division_code + "' and Delete_Status = 0", connection);
                 //SQl command builder is used to get data from database based on query
                 MySqlCommandBuilder cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
                 //Fill data table
                 da.Fill(dt);
                 //assigning data table to Datagridview
                 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                 //Resize the Datagridview column to fit the gridview columns with data in datagridview
                 dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
                 connection.Close();
```

In That I got

[image]

Here u see the two columns of Textbox is empty. and other two is added.

I don't want to remove the textbox. So I want to populate the data with in my textbox, not a auto generated one.,..

Please help me, to solve this problem....

Thanks, I got the value in template Textbox columns. But the Last two columns of auto generated columns are added. How to remove that.

```
connection.Open();
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();                 
                 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select admin_no,name from " + FormName + " where class_code='" + class_code + "' and division_code='" + division_code + "' and Delete_Status = 0", connection);                 
                 MySqlCommandBuilder cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);                 
                 da.Fill(dt);                 
                 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;                                 
                 dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "admin_no";
                 dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "name";
                 connection.Close();
```

[image]

Help Me again Please.

Sorry i forgot "dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;".

Thanks I got my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName="name_of_field"`. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx) article.

PS: You should have to use `Parameterized` query instead of hard-coded sql string to prevent [sql-injection.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks. But where Can i add this code after "dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;" or before..

Comment: @Sagotharan - I think you've added columns via Columns property(wizard) of dataGridview control in designer. So open Columns property and set DataPropertyName property.

Comment: Thanks, I got the text box values. But the last two columns was also included. How can i remove.

Comment: @Sagotharan - You have to turn off the autogen columns.  `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

Answer (score 2):

Go to your datagridview properties.

Search for Columns.. On your unbound Admin No Column set its DataproperyName to admin_no

This will bind your DataTable Column admin_no to datagridview unbound Admin No column automatically. Do this also on your other unbound columns.

Regards